# Powershell script for comparing the services of remote machines with the target set of services

Tags: windows-services, powershell-4.0

I have been trying to create a new PS script wherein it will compare the below values inserted in the 'TargetServices'.csv with the output file 'services.csv' created by executing the first few lines of script and eventually whichever services are running/stopped for the remote computers, it should paste the result of 'MachineName', 'Name'(ServiceName), 'Status' into a 3rd separate file 'FinalSheet'.csv.
Then accordingly, I would like to add a Hash to the services which will show up in the 'FinalSheet'.csv with a '#' added to the service name column which are not my in my 'TargetServices' list and are already in Stopped state.

### I tried using the below script:

$file1 = "C:\Terraform\FinalSheet.csv"
$computers = "LIN49003150"
Get-service -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object MachineName, Name, DisplayName, Status, StartType | ForEach-Object{
if($*.Status -eq "Running")
{
Write-Host $*.MachineName,$*.Name, $*.DisplayName, $*.Status, $*.StartType -ForegroundColor Green
}
$_
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Terraform\services.csv"

$filea = Import-Csv C:\Terraform\TargetServices.csv
$fileb = Import-Csv C:\Terraform\Services.csv

Compare-Object $filea $fileb -Property MachineName, name, Status | Select-Object MachineName, Name, Status | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $file1

---

However I get the complete list of my machine services in the final sheet and services..
Please guide me...